# Data from same table with different where clauses into same view

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to get two kinds of data from same table into a view. I tried adding a join to same table with a different alias but it caused some null values.

I want the datatable as a single row , if possible. I know this can be done with union operator too but it causes multiple rows.

Here is my select

```
SELECT 
COUNT(PO.OrderID) AS MerkezOnaySiparisAdet, SUM(PO.TotalPromotionPrice) AS MerkezOnayToplamSatis,
COUNT(PO2.OrderID)  AS DepoOnaySiparişAdet, SUM(PO2.TotalPromotionPrice) AS DepoOnayToplamSatis
FROM PrmOrder PO

LEFT JOIN PrmOrder PO2 ON PO.OrderID = PO2.OrderId AND (PO2.OrderStatusID != 1 AND PO2.IsOrderApproved = 1 AND PO2.IsInventoryApproved = 0 AND (PO2.OrderStatusID = 2 OR PO2.OrderStatusID = 3))

WHERE 1=1
AND PO.OrderStatusID != 1
AND PO.IsOrderApproved = 0
AND (PO.OrderStatusID = 2 OR PO.OrderStatusID = 3)
```

What is the correct way of doing this?

Comment: provide sample data and desired result please

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: the problem is that you are doing a left join, it will select all the rows from PO and populate PO2 with nulls when the join condition is not met. You may need to do an inner join, or alternatively just join by ID and bring the other conditions for PO2 to the where clause.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, this isn't the best way, but you can use subquery. For example

```
   SELECT 
 A1.Sum1,
 A2.Sum2 FROM   
 (
   SELECT 
     SUM(sod.OrderQty) sum1,
     1 joinnumber
   FROM   
     Sales.SalesOrderDetail sod
   WHERE  
     sod.ProductID = 772
 ) AS A1
   JOIN (
          SELECT 
            SUM(sod.OrderQty) sum2,
            1 joinnumber
          FROM   
            Sales.SalesOrderDetail sod
          WHERE  
            sod.ProductID = 773
        ) AS A2
     ON A1.joinnumber = A2.joinnumber
```